# Выбросы на датасете

Tags: python, dataframe, машинное-обучение, анализ-данных, scikit-learn

[image: Обнаружение выбросы]

Detecting outliers.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(18, 2))
plt.boxplot(df[['MEDV']], vert=False)
plt.show()
```

Пытаюсь анализировать "Boston House Price" датасет.
Но не могу уточнит: мы можем ли сказать что там есть выбросы?

Comment: да, мы можем сказать, что есть выбросы. дальше-то что? вам же это надо как-то программно определить, я подозреваю.

Answer (score 1):

Точки, которые вы видите за пределами концов усов и есть выбросы.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]